# TableView is delegated, populates but wont group

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I am having a weird problem and i couldn`t find a solution (or something similar).
The thing is, my UITableView Populates with initial info (for testing), but no matter what i do i can't seem to put it to grouped style (i can select it on the UI but it wont show)

I initially started a TabBar project and added a third navigationController view in the tabs.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
NSMutableArray *tableData;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tableData;

-(void)initTableData;

@end
```

This is the header, and as you can see it has nothing out of the ordinary. The following code is inside the .m file of the header i just posted(ill only be posting uncommented code:

```
@synthesize tableData;

-(void)initTableData
{
    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tableData addObject:@"Cidade"];
    [tableData addObject:@"Veículo"];
    [tableData addObject:@"Ano"];
    [tableData addObject:@"Valor"];
    [tableData addObject:@"Cor"];
    [tableData addObject:@"Combustível"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Busca";
    UIBarButtonItem *_backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = _backButton;
    [self initTableData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 6;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [tableData release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Nothing out of the ordinary again as you can see...
Any idea of what may be causing this? I tried

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    // Override initWithStyle: if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
```

because i don't know what else to do. (also didn't worked)
Again, i got the delegate and datasource set to File`s Owner.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Set the tab bar controller as the window's root view controller and display.

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    RootViewController *rvc = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Probably on the same note, i can`t seem to push a view after clicking on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have modified the `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style` initializer to return  a `UITableView` with a grouped style, do you call this initializer when you initialize the `RootViewController`?

```
RootViewController *rvc = [[RootViewController] alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Comment: No. Would that be the didFinishLaunching method on appDelegate.m?
Because it already sets the rootview as the tabbar, and it got me confused here.
Also, i tried pushing a view when i click the table, but that's also not happening. I'm guessing i'm forgetting something very basic, since i'm no expert.

Comment: Yes, where you create the RootViewController. Show the code from didFinishLaunching method.

Comment: i put the code on the main post, at the end.
I'm a newbie so, i'm sorry if you spot some stupid errors.

Comment: After initializing the RootViewController add: self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:rvc];

Comment: Create a new iOS project with "Tabbed Application" template and examine how the view hierarchy is generated to get a better understanding what's going on. :)

Answer (score 1):

Grouped tables respond to the sections. You only have 1 section listed so you will only see the 1 group. Try and add a 2nd tableData for the 2nd group and return 2 sections. You will also have to split the data in your -cellForRowAtIndexPath by section as well to make sure the data goes to the right section.

```
if (indexpath.section == 0) {
   // first section and first tableData
}
if (indexpath.section == 1) {
   // second section and second tableData
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, it only duplicates my data but no grouping is formed.

Comment: Is your table set as a grouped table? You can change it to grouped in IB or via code. By default, the tables are just set to single.